# Trying to get applet to work on live server

Tags: java, javascript, applet

The applet I build runs well off my localhost but when I upload it to server and look at url I recive these java applet errors: Are there extra steps I may have missed to get the applet to work when transferring files?

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1008821359 in class file PrintJob/Print_Runner
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the upload was correct?

The error message " Incompatible magic value" shows an invalid class file.

Can you also check, that the class file can be retrieved from the URL without error? If the server returns an error, a similar Java error will occur. Try to retrieve the class file with curl or something similar.

Comment: ok. let me be more specific. I can upload it to something.com/folder1/folder2/Package/class_file but not to something.com/folder2/Package/class_file. I need the second url to work though and not the first.